# Web page width on Android tablet

Tags: android, hybrid

I am beginner on hybrid development. So I wanted to know the best practice of web design width when we working on tablet size?

Comment: You should enable the viewport tag on the web page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are the sizes I like to design for; not all of these may be ideal for your needs, however I find this tend to provide the cater to the most common configurations of devices out there. When I refer to device width, it is in "device independent pixels" :P

**1024px**

This is the typical device width of 1:1 scale tablet in landscape mode, which also lends itself well to larger computer monitors.

iPad Technical Specifications Note: iPad with Retina display still maintains a device width in the browser of 1024px in landscape, and 768px in portrait
Android Developers: Supporting Multiple Screens

**1023-980px**

This is the default viewport width for iOS devices (which is supposed to represent the "average" website width), which also lends itself well to average sized computer monitors.

iOS Developer Library: Configuring the Viewport

**979-768px**

This is the device width of an Apple iPad in portrait mode. Note: Many 16:9 Android tablets have a device width of 720px: Android Developers: Supporting Multiple Screens

iPad Technical Specifications Note: iPad with Retina display still maintains a device width in the browser of 1024px in landscape, and 768px in portrait

**767-480px**

This is the typical device width of 1:1 scale phone in landscape mode.

iOS Developer Library: Layout and Metrics on iPhone and iPod touch
Android Developers: Supporting Multiple Screens
Blackberry Development Guide: Developing applications for different screen sizes